# Where does Macports install GNU sed when I install coreutils port?

Tags: sed, macports

Where does Macports install the GNU sed when I install coreutils port?  I want to use GNU sed instead of BSD sed on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

coreutils in macports does *not* install GNU sed.

GNU sed is instead installed by port gsed and will end up as `/opt/local/bin/gsed`

Comment: If you'd like to use GNU sed as the default sed then add `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin` early in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: At least at this time, this answer appears to be incorrect. `port contents coreutils | grep sed` yields nothing.

Comment: @oarfish The answer is correct it says "coreutils in macports does not install GNU sed. " that would lead me to expect the command you ran should be empty

Comment: Sorry that was a huge brainfart on my part. Not sure what I was reading.